# appending new option to dropdown list dynamically as selected

Tags: jquery

**Appending new Option**
using JQuery dynamically it works fine

```
$('#department').append(new Option(response.departmentname,response.departmentid));
```

I want to make it as a selected ?

Comment: check the console for errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set its(select element with `id` department) value via `chaining`,

```
$('#department')
   .append(new Option(response.departmentname,response.departmentid))
     .val(response.departmentid);
```

Comment: added at end of the list but not it as selected

Comment: This should work, can you reproduce it in a fiddle..? Please see this. http://jsfiddle.net/S5fp7/1/

Comment: @Rajaparabhu Aravindasamy in my case default option is as selected '<option value="0" selected="selected">--Select--</option>' may be because of this my code is not working, i.e. option appended but not as selected. Please how help me to do

Answer (score 5):

You can set the 4th options to true:

```
new Option(response.departmentname, response.departmentid, false, true)
```

From [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement.Option):

> "selected" (a boolean to indicate whether the option will be "selected"; if omitted, it will not be selected).

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/S5fp7/

Comment: Great catch.  I just caught the part of the documentation describing the 3rd & 4th params and how they differ.

Comment: @JeremyMiller Well you can also set the 3rd option to true, it will act like `selected` attribute.

Comment: Yeah.  That's what confused me at first.  I guess I am too lazy with jQuery and simply dump in the HTML and let it do the DOM construction.

Comment: @dsq in my case default option is as selected '<option value="0" selected="selected">--Select--</option>' may be because of this my code is not working, i.e. option appended but not as selected. Please how help me to do

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('#department').append(new Option(response.departmentname, response.departmentid))
$('#department').val(response.departmentid);
```

[check out this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K3HTs/2/)

[on click of a button](http://jsfiddle.net/K3HTs/4/)

Comment: @A J in my case default option is as selected '<option value="0" selected="selected">--Select--</option>' may be because of this my code is not working, i.e. option appended but not as selected. Please how help me to do

Comment: I have updated the fiddle .. it works fine.. should be something else .. please check for any console errors.

Comment: check both fiddles .. was this helpful?